# How can I create business type payment profile?

Tags: google-play-console

I created a new google developer account as a organization type for our company.

When I paid $25 to create account, a new payment profile was automatically created as a individual.
In order for me to upload the app to the store, I need to authenticate myself, but they required for my personal information, not my company's information.

I think it's because my payment profile that I paid $25 to create developer account is a individual type.

I contacted the Google payment team.
But they said you can create a new payment profile on the play console.
I said I knew that, and I wanted to know how to identify our company on this account.
Then, they say it's not our job and they transfer this issue to the team.
I've been repeating this for two weeks.

How can I create a payment profile a business type when I create developer account?

Comment: I'm just working through the same problem myself, support is saying to create a payment profile first but there doesn't seem to be a way to make one without first creating an account.

Comment: have you got any solution here? facing the same

Answer (score 2):

### RCA

Finally got this working, with much help from dev-support. The key issue to work around is this:

- There's three separate entities that have to work in concert: Google Pay, Google Wallet and Google Play Console.
- When you sign up for an `Organization` account (Google Play) and pay the registration fee (Google Pay) an Individual-type Payments Profile (Google Wallet) is created and linked to the Play account.
- Finally when you apply for verification the error you mentioned occurs.

## Solution

Since re-linking the payment profile isn't an option, the only thing to do is start fresh; These are the steps that worked for me:

### Clear the existing account

1. Close the payments profile. Instructions [here](https://support.google.com/paymentscenter/answer/7688666?hl=en).
2. Inform support of the situation and confirm that you'll get the refund once you close the account. Once they confirm, close the play account.

### Create a Business-type Payments Profile

1. Using your registration email address, go to [Google Wallet](https://developers.google.com/wallet).
2. Scroll down to bottom then click "Get Started".
3. Enter your Business name and location.
4. Under Business Profile tab, click "Set up your payments profile".[image: screenshot showing the business profile section of google-wallet; in the middle pane there's a section named 'Business identity' that has a button saying 'Set up your payments profile']
5. Create new payments profile, then fill out the required information. Click the save button. [image: Screenshot showing the create-new-payments-profile form, with a buttong to click to create a new profile if one already exists]
6. Refresh the page, and you should see the newly created organization/business payments profile.

### Create a new Google Play account

1. Follow the same steps as you originally did, enter your company details etc
2. Once created, navigate to "Payments Profile" in the left nav. [image: screenshot showing the Payments profile button nested under Setup]
3. At this point you should be able to link the Business-type Payment profile to your play-account.

   - apologies for the lack of screenshot here but I already finished linking it by the time of writing this

All the best! :)